# Windows Creators Update Crashes old Apps - classes not registered

Tags: .net, windows-10

We have a legacy application (no longer supported) that now will not install properly with Creators Update. If we use DISM to set up .Net 3.5 Framework before installing on previous versions of Windows 10 (Anniversary and earlier) it installs and works just fine. But trying the same installation technique does NOT work with Creators.

Does anyone have any idea what may have changed that now keeps the classes/dlls whatever from registering? What is the correction for this?

As I said earlier, it is not supported anymore so the vendor won't help. And I have no choice - I have to use this application. I know I can install the Anniversary update, install the application, then update, but our customer is requesting we use the latest version of Windows 10 for the base installation.

Please - does anyone know how to fix the registration errors? If we can do something after the installation to correct it, that is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't answer the question of why the application can't register the dll's itself, I found that I can run a script after the installation to register the dll and ocx files, which then allows the application to run.

I really wish Microsoft would tell you exactly what they are doing in these updates instead of just hyping the new features.